# mongoose select with range always return null

Tags: node.js, select, mongoose, range

hei im try to get data with range between field_1 and field_2 but it always return null

here my code

```
  let limit = 10;
  let skip = 0;

  let conditions = {
            depth_1 : {"$gte" :parseInt(req.body.depth_1)},
            depth_2 : {"$lte" :parseInt(req.body.depth_2)}
 }
  let showImage = await Image.find(conditions).limit(limit).skip(skip).exec(function(err, docs){

        res.send(docs)
```

these code always returning null even i have that data in my db

my json data:

```
[
{
    "mode": "W",
    "_id": "5bd3e4890ec2f91a7d9309e9",
    "filename": "VH009_15.95-20.95_W.png.png",
    "path": "/home/harisman/dugong/H/bismillah/public/images/VH009_15.95-20.95_W.png.png",
    "hold_id": "VH009",
    "depth_1": 1595,
    "depth_2": 2095,
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2018-10-27T04:07:37.785Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-27T04:07:37.785Z"
}
]
```

my req.body :

```
{
"depth_1" : 1595,
"depth_2" : 2095    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
let showImage = await Image.find(conditions).limit(limit)
   .skip(skip).exec(function(err, docs) {})
```

You are using await and callback ... try this:

```
let showImage = await Image.find(conditions).limit(limit)
   .skip(skip).exec()
```

or this should work as well:

```
let showImage = Image.find(conditions).limit(limit)
   .skip(skip).exec().then(docs => console.log(docs))
```

Both depend on the `exec` actually providing full-fledged promise